# Dark-Mode toggling Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Following is my DarkMode.jsx component. When I switch button, dark mode apply only to navbar. Other remaining parts of website do not change to dark theme. How should I keep state updated everywhere
using Material-UI?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { Switch } from "@mui/material"

export default function DarkMode() {
  // state to manage the dark mode
  const [toggleDarkMode, setToggleDarkMode] = useState(true);

  // function to toggle the dark mode as true or false
  const toggleDarkTheme = () => {
    setToggleDarkMode(!toggleDarkMode);
  };

  // applying the primary and secondary theme colors
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: toggleDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light', // handle the dark mode state on toggle
      primary: {
        main: '#90caf9',
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#131052',
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <h2>Toggle Dark mode</h2>
        <Switch checked={toggleDarkMode} onChange={toggleDarkTheme} />
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

I add my `DarkMode` component inside Main.jsx after `Navbar` component.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'
// import App from './App'
import Navbar from './Components/components/Navbar';
import Hero from './Components/components/Hero';
import About from './Components/components/About';
import Feature from './Components/components/Feature';
import Card from './Components/components/Card';
import Opensource from './Components/components/Opensource';
import Footer from './Components/components/Footer';
import Workshop from './Components/components/Workshop';
import DarkMode from './Components/components/DarkMode';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Navbar />
    <DarkMode/ >
    <Hero />
    <Card />
    <About />
    <Feature />
    <Workshop />
    <Opensource />
    <Footer />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

first in DarkMode Component you must return children props
why? because in your structure you create theme only in the darkmode component and the other doesnt have accese to that

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import {  Switch,  } from "@mui/material"
export default function DarkMode({children}) {

  // state to manage the dark mode
  const [toggleDarkMode, setToggleDarkMode] = useState(true);

  // function to toggle the dark mode as true or false
  const toggleDarkTheme = () => {
    setToggleDarkMode(!toggleDarkMode);
  };

  // applying the primary and secondary theme colors
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: toggleDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light', // handle the dark mode state on toggle
      primary: {
        main: '#90caf9',
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#131052',
      },
    },
  });

  return (
   <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
    <CssBaseline/>
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <h2>Toggle Dark mode</h2>
        <Switch checked={toggleDarkMode} onChange={toggleDarkTheme} />
    </div>
   </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

and change the main.jsx to this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'
// import App from './App'
import Navbar from './Components/components/Navbar';
import Hero from './Components/components/Hero';
import About from './Components/components/About';
import Feature from './Components/components/Feature';
import Card from './Components/components/Card';
import Opensource from './Components/components/Opensource';
import Footer from './Components/components/Footer';
import Workshop from './Components/components/Workshop';
import DarkMode from './Components/components/DarkMode';



ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <DarkMode> 
   <Navbar/>
     <Hero />
     <Card />
     <About />
     <Feature />
     <Workshop/>
     <Opensource />
     <Footer />
   </DarkMode>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a global dark mode that applies to the entire website, you need to manage the dark mode state at a higher level than just within the `DarkMode` component. One way to do this is by lifting the state up to a common parent component that wraps your entire application. This way, the dark mode state is accessible by all components that need to be aware of it.

Create a state in the parent component (e.g., `App.jsx`) to manage the dark mode state.
Pass down the state and the function to toggle dark mode as props to the `DarkMode` component.
Update the `DarkMode` component to use the passed-down state and function.

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Components/components/Navbar';
import Hero from './Components/components/Hero';
import About from './Components/components/About';
import Feature from './Components/components/Feature';
import Card from './Components/components/Card';
import Opensource from './Components/components/Opensource';
import Footer from './Components/components/Footer';
import Workshop from './Components/components/Workshop';
import DarkMode from './Components/components/DarkMode';

function App() {
  const [toggleDarkMode, setToggleDarkMode] = useState(true);

  const toggleDarkTheme = () => {
    setToggleDarkMode(!toggleDarkMode);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <DarkMode toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode} toggleDarkTheme={toggleDarkTheme} />
      <Hero />
      <Card />
      <About />
      <Feature />
      <Workshop />
      <Opensource />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**DarkMode.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { Switch } from '@mui/material';

export default function DarkMode({ toggleDarkMode, toggleDarkTheme }) {
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: toggleDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light',
      primary: {
        main: '#90caf9',
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#131052',
      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <h2>Toggle Dark mode</h2>
        <Switch checked={toggleDarkMode} onChange={toggleDarkTheme} />
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Now, the dark mode state is managed in the `App` component, and both `Navbar` and `DarkMode` components have access to the same state. This way, when you toggle dark mode in the `DarkMode` component, it will affect the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

The `DarkMode` component holds the theme state and renders the `ThemeProvider` component which provides the context, but then it doesn't render any sub-ReactTree that can consume the provided context value.

Update the `DarkMode` component to render it's `children` prop, and wrapp all the UI components that need to consume the theme context.

```
export default function DarkMode({ children }) {
  // state to manage the dark mode
  const [toggleDarkMode, setToggleDarkMode] = useState(true);

  // function to toggle the dark mode as true or false
  const toggleDarkTheme = () => {
    setToggleDarkMode(!toggleDarkMode);
  };

  // applying the primary and secondary theme colors
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      mode: toggleDarkMode ? 'dark' : 'light', // handle the dark mode state on toggle
      primary: {
        main: '#90caf9',
      },
      secondary: {
        main: '#131052',

      },
    },
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div
        style={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          alignItems: 'center'
        }}
      >
        <h2>Toggle Dark mode</h2>
        <Switch checked={toggleDarkMode} onChange={toggleDarkTheme} />
      </div>
      {children} // <-- render children under provider
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
  .render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <DarkMode> // <-- provides theme context
        {/* all children consume theme context */}
        <Navbar />
        <Hero />
        <Card />
        <About />
        <Feature />
        <Workshop />
        <Opensource />
        <Footer />
      </DarkMode>
    </React.StrictMode>,
  );
```